# How to set minDate on vue using flatpickr dynamically?

Tags: vue.js, flatpickr

package version.

- "vue": "2.6.12",
- ["vue-flatpickr-component"](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-flatpickr-component): "8.1.6",

I tried to set minimum date as flat-pickr's property.
but it doesn't recognize startdate data (it was from the calendar to enter the startdate).
I read flatpickr doc but I just found a way to enter just "string" type on minDate like this "2022-11-07".

How to set mindate directively?

It's not working (no error)

```html
<flat-pickr
  :disabled="form.promotion.indefinitePeriod || !form.startDate"
  v-model="form.endDate"
  class="form-control"
  variant="secondary"
  :class="'checkbox-' + form.promotion.indefinitePeriod"
  :config="endDateConfig"
  :placeholder="placeholder"
  :minDate="form.startDate"
  ref="endDate"
/>
```

set config like this
but error

> "form" is used before its initialization

```js
private endDateConfig = { 
  mode: 'single', 
  wrap: true,
  minDate: this.form.startDate,
  onChange : (selectedDates: object, dateStr: string, instance: any) => {
    if(dateStr.length === 0) return;
    if(dateStr < this.form.startDate){
      return toastWarning(this.$toast, this.$t('종료일이 시작일을 앞섰습니다').toString());
    }
    // 시작일이 비어있을 떄
    if(this.form.startDate.length <= 0){
      this.$refs.startDate.fp.open()
      return toastWarning(this.$toast, this.$t('시작일을 입력해주세요').toString());
    }
    console.log("2222222")
    this.form.rangeDate = `${this.form.startDate} to ${dateStr}`;
    this.onChangeRangeDate();
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah it's better to read :) you mean i have to notify all the packages's exact version related on this code? @kissu

Comment: Nah it's good like that, simply sharing which one you're using because there are wrapper, specific versions etc. Mainly to help the people that may help you not wasting time trying to figuring out what you're using.

Comment: i solve it by using inline code like this :config="{ mode: 'single', minDate: form.startDate}"

Comment: Hey, feel free to post it as an answer.